# EditText has two underlines

Tags: android, android-edittext

Getting quite frustrated with this issue.

I have got two underlines for all my `EditText` and I don't know why this is happening.

How do I remove the black underline color?

[image: EditText has two underlines]

Comment: after typing decimal no press space. then check still it is showing

Comment: On the Android XML File, under "Text Fields" there is a 'Number Decimal' field option. If you're using only number inputs, it'd be better to use that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The turquoise underline is part of the default `EditText` widget background. You can remove it by setting the `background` XML attribute to `@null`.

The black underline is likely caused by predictive text. This can be corrected by adjusting your `inputType`, also in XML.